# How to load multiple local files in pure JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load multiple xml files into variables. Ideally I would like to have list of containing content of unknown number of files. something like this `files = [file1.content, file2.content...]` I would like to keep it pure JavaScript if possible, but searching through the internet it seems very difficult. It is previewer of xml files that would be run locally and most likely in modern browsers

```
const xmlFiles = ['font.ufo/glyphs/A_.glif', 'font.ufo/glyphs/B.glif']
let xmlData = []

const load = new Promise(function(printData) {
  for (i in xmlFiles) {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("GET",xmlFiles[i])
    request.onload=function(){
        xmlData.push(request.responseText)
    }
  request.send()
  }
  printData()
})

load.then(function(){
  console.log(xmlData, xmlData.length)
  console.log('This is printData function')
})
```

Now I receive only empty list. Though when I open the console, I see the content. When I ask for length of the list in the then function, it says zero.
I don't know if I chose the right approach, I very hope so.. please I will appreciate any tips. THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all` allows to pass an array of promises, and when all are resolved then inside `then` an array with resolved values is passed.

Below, `load` function doesn’t run a loop, instead file is passed as a param. Then each file is loaded and resolved, and `xmlData`—now a local variable for `then` handler—should have what you’re expecting.

For the `Promise.all` argument we’re mapping each of `xmlFiles` to a promise with `load` function. (This could be even `Promise.all(xmlFiles.map(load))` but I left it more verbose.)

```
const xmlFiles = ['font.ufo/glyphs/A_.glif', 'font.ufo/glyphs/B.glif']

const load = (file) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  request.open("GET", file)
  request.onload = function() {
    resolve(request.responseText);
  }
  request.send();
})

Promise
  .all(xmlFiles.map((file) => load(file)))
  .then(function(xmlData){
    console.log(xmlData, xmlData.length)
    console.log('This is printData function')
  })
```

I wrote this without testing but this should give you an idea at least.

Comment: Thanks, I understand a bit more! it works. I it still very complex but I will implement it once I understand it. I found out that false in `xmlhttp.open("GET", xmlFiles[i], false)` loads it chronologically it gets the job done as well.

Comment: Maybe `fetch`, which returns Promise by design, would allow you to simplify your code.